# How do a resolve the error where Microsoft Reserved Partition isn't detected?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I installed Ubuntu 20.10 a couple months ago, and I performed the setup that made Ubuntu as my native OS. However, Windows 10 was still accessible from GRUB and ran perfectly when I would boot into it. I decided that I wanted to partition some storage for Windows so that I could use this new tablet I was gifted for lessons and recordings. My issue is that when I open Gparted, there's an exclamation point next to Microsoft Reserved Partition. The information in the partition file says:

**Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:**

**- The file system is damaged**

**- The file system is unknown to GParted**

**- There is no file system available (unformatted)**

**- The device entry /dev/sda2 is missing**

Furthermore, if I try to resize the partition in my hard disk I receive an error saying:

**Error unmounting /dev/sdb2: target is busy (udisks-error-quark, 14)**

I apologies if I seem naive, but I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to Linux distros. Any help resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since unformatted, will also show as an error in gparted. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition But will have a valid GUID assigned, so gparted should be updated to ignore it. Gparted also gives the same error on a BIOS install of Ubuntu/grub to gpt drive that requires an unformatted bios_grub partition which will also have a valid GUID. Windows UEFI/gpt partitions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require a resolution.  Let Windows manage windows partitions.

Also, the Microsoft Reserved partition shouldn't be re-partitioned or messed with.  It is not your main Windows partition - it is a partition reserved by Windows for booting, I believe.  If you want to re-allocate space for Windows, then you need to extend or shrink the larger NTFS partition that represents your windows drive.

FWIW, my Gparted shows exactly the same thing yours does.  My reserved partition is 16 MB (Mega, not Giga) - I presume yours is also quite small.  The next partition on my disk is my main Windows data partition, which is around 125 GB for me.